# C# StreamWriter how to format file into categories

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am currently trying to format my file that I am creating with a StreamWriter

```
fileWriter.WriteLine(record.Account + "," + record.FirstName + "," +
record.LastName + "," + record.Balance );
```

This is the current code, the output looks something like this:

Acc,firstName,lastName,balance

```
1,a,d,4
2,b,e,5
3,c,f,5
```

New data is added to the file everytime I press a button.

How can I make it so that that Account number is on one line, firstname on another line, lastname on another and balance on another line such as:

```
1, 2, 3
a, b, c
d, e, f
4, 5, 6
```

Comment: That cannot work, because then you have to insert the new values in the middle of the file. There is only one possibility, every time you want to insert new values read the complete file in a collection (e.g. a list) add the values and write the data back to the file. But this would only work when the file is not to large.

Answer (score 0):

The way i see it you have two options. 
Option number 1 is to re-map you collection to resemble the data you want to write.
Option number 2 is to iterate initialize number of string you want for lines if it indeed only 4 of them then iterate through the collection adding items to respecting line and finally writing it all to the file.